# Why does Chrome show an odd-shaped highlight around my image link when I tab to it?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When tab to a link on my webpage in Chrome, the tab hightlight box around this image link appears like this:

[alt text http://www.chordfusion.com/images_so/wtf.png](http://www.chordfusion.com/images_so/wtf.png)

(the orange border is what Chrome shows as the highlight box)

The HTML/CSS isn't all that special:

```
<a href="download.html">
    <img src="images/download_button.png" class="downloadbutton"/>
</a>

img.downloadbutton
{
    margin-right: 0px;
    border:none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, either there's a space at the end of the `img` line, or it's HTML treating new lines as white space. Try putting the contents of the `a` all one line and see if it goes away then.

Comment: Wow, that was exactly it. Never would have guessed! Thanks!